What's the purpose of resistor in series with feedback capacitor in opamp I\V stage circuit?
In some designs of I\V stage circuits for DAC chips (for example, the ESS ES9038PRO Evaluation Board), there's a place for a resistor in series with a feedback capacitor (R7_1 in this case):

Source: 'ES9038PRO - 8 CHANNEL 64 PIN LQFP' rev. 1.3, Oct 3 2016, p.3, publisher: ESS TECHNOLOGY, INC.
I tend to see that the schematics of expensive DACs include that resistor (typ. around ~100 Ohm), while more affordable DACs tend to simplify things and connect the left terminal of the capacitor (C8_1 on the sample above) to the opamp inverting input.
Also, I can see instances of a similarly placed resistor in a differential active LPF circuits for RCA outputs, for example resistor R66_1 below:

Source: 'ES9038PRO - 8 CHANNEL 64 PIN LQFP' rev. 1.3, Oct 3 2016, p.3, publisher: ESS TECHNOLOGY, INC.
NOTE: I included the samples above just for quick demonstration purpose, NOT because this question is somehow related to these specific samples. It's meant to be a generic question about a DAC I\V stage or a LPF filter circuit design for Hi-Fi audio.

What could be the purpose of those resistors in such I\V stage and\or LPF circuits for audio?
How to calculate the resistors values?


What would happen if you remove the resistor?

@Colin Good question :) To answer it, we have to know what its purpose is first. But as I understand it, the circuit would become a regular I\V stage + LPF filter. My first wild guess is that the resistor lowers the Q factor of the LPF.

Are you aware that these resistors are specified with 0 Ohm? Note, this does not invalidate your question.

@AlexanderAbakumov You have some good insight. Since this is an evaluation board, you have some freedom on how you study frequency response. The comment above mine provides a rundown on various conditions. Perhaps it might be good to simulate everything first to tinker around without needing to do some solder work. But once you've selected/specified your design, you can try it out.

@periblepsis Not populating the resistor isn't meant to be an option. As I'm mentioning in the I tend to see that the schematics of expensive DACs... section of the question, the 2 options in real designs are: 1. R = 0 Ohm (which turns it to plain LPF, I guess); 2. 0 Ohm < R << Infinity (typ. 100 Ohm). So, the actual point of interest of this question is the 2nd option vs the 1st option: why would one put ~100 Ohm resistor there? And, depending, on the answer: how to calculate its value?

@AlexanderAbakumov It's only function would be to add that zero. I'll leave it to experts to tell you why.

@periblepsis I might be missing the exact meaning of your It's only function would be to add that zero. response, but if you, for example, look into the old ES9008 ESS Application Notes docs (you're great at googling :), you could find that indeed they've recommended placing 100 Ohm resistors in both I\V stage and LPF circuits that old days. The samples I've posted just leave that decision on end product engineers. What I'm looking for are ideas on the motivation for doing it this way.

@Alexander I absolutely did not read that document. I only validated its schematic. As far as why the zero, I can calculate the behavior down to the Nth decimal place for you. (The zero will be at the parallel of the two resistors and the capacitor. or about 3.6-3.7 MHz and the gain will be about -6 dB out there if the datasheet's output impedance is correct [+9 dB near DC].) But I'm not offering myself as an expert about why and I'm not offering to read the doc to educate myself and interpret it. Others can likely offer much better experience for you. I'm an idiot.

@periblepsis I've mentioned the old Application Notes (for the different chip, BTW) with the sole purpose of giving an example of a real design which utilizes those resistors in both I\V stage and LPF with a non-zero values. This explains a core of the question from the practical engineering standpoint: why would we want to use those in such circuits? The doc doesn't say anything about it; it just presents the design with 100 Ohm resistors. The value of 0 Ohm makes the circuits trivial, so it's just a reference point to compare with. The true interest is in the purpose of having them > 0

@Alexander The pole position is $\omega_{P}=\frac1{C_8\left(R_7+R_9\right)}$ (first schematic.) So using a non-zero value pulls the pole backwards towards DC, while also adding a zero at  $\omega{_Z}=\frac1{C_8\left(R_7,\vert\vert,R_9\right)}$. The near-DC gain isn't changed. As you increase the value, both the pole and the zero moves towards DC and the zero's shelf increases in gain. I won't guess about why $100:\Omega$ is desired because that would require me to study the application to have anything more serious to offer.

We can only analyze the circuit what the capacitor does or changes in that circuit.
It changes the standard inverting first order low-pass filter into an inverting first order low pass shelving filter.
Standard formulas for such filters apply how to calculate the component values. You can even simulate the circuit what it does to a signal.
The harder part is to know or understand why there would be a need to change the filter type into a shelving filter. Could it be due to the properties or imperfections of the DAC output signal, op-amp model which may not process it well, their combined effect or just because the signal is audio and you want to have some specific filtering curve.
We may only find clues why it would be necessary from what a shelving filter does compared to a basic filter. The shelving filter allows you to set DC gain and AC gain separately.
Also the DAC output is a series of high frequency current pulses or steps. As the op-amp is not ideal, it cannot respond to step or pulse signals immediately. A capacitor between output and input will actually couple the input step to output. Having a non-zero value resistor in series with the capacitor will decrease the amount of direct coupling through the capacitor to output.

You're right that that by increasing the value of the R66_1 resistor on the 2nd (LPF) circuit, we could turn it into the shelving filter. Thank you for pointing to that! But what about the 1st (I\V stage) circuit? It doesn't have a resistor between a source and the opamp inverting input, so, technically, it's not even a filter circuit, right?

@AlexanderAbakumov Actually it is a filter too. The DAC output in this case is not voltage but current, so it does not need a resistor on the input. The circuit acts as a current-to-voltage converter but with a low pass response. The inverting input terminal is kept at same voltage as non-inverting so it's actually input current that counts, and if there were an input resistor it would convert input voltage to input current.

Great, that makes sense! Thank you! Would it be correct to assume that this I\V stage is equal to a trivial inverting OpAmp low-pass shelving filter and assume that the R3 (the resistor between the source and the inverting input) value (like in 6.1.1 Inverting OpAmp Shelving Filters) is equal to the DAC output impedance, then?

@AlexanderAbakumov no, because a DAC with current output has infinite output impedance, at least in theory. So there is no voltage output that needs to convert into some current with some impedance. The current is the output and the op-amp with the feedback resistor converts the current output signal into voltage output signal. Since the DAC output is current, ideally speaking, the resistance between DAC output and inverting op-amp is irrelevant.
